# Drop log messages containing a specific string

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

So I have log messages of the format :

```
[INFO]  <blah.blah>       2016-06-27 21:41:38,263 some text
[INFO]  <blah.blah>       2016-06-28 18:41:38,262 some other text
```

Now I want to drop all logs that does not contain a specific string "xyz"  and keep all the rest. I also want to index timestamp.

[grokdebug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com) is not helping much.

This is my attempt :

```
input {
    file {
         path => "/Users/username/Desktop/validateLogconf/logs/*"
      start_position => "beginning"

   }
}

filter {

  grok {
      match => {
      "message" => '%{SYSLOG5424SD:loglevel}  <%{JAVACLASS:job}>       %{GREEDYDATA:content}'
      }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "Date", "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    locale => en
  }

}

output {
  stdout {
codec => plain {
                        charset => "ISO-8859-1"
                }

}
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://localhost:9201"
        index => "hello"

  }
}
```

I am new to grok so patterns above might not be making sense. Please help.

Comment: You should have ask two question instead of only one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To drop the message that does not contain the string `xyz`:

```
if ([message] !~ "xyz") {
    drop { }
}
```

Your grok pattern is not grabbing the date part of your logs.
Once you have a field from your grok pattern containing the date, you can invoque the date filter on this field.
So your grok filter should look like this:

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => '%{SYSLOG5424SD:loglevel}  <%{JAVACLASS:job}>       %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Date} %{GREEDYDATA:content}'
    }
}
```

I added a part to grab the date, which will be in the field `Date`. Then you can use the date filter:

```
date {
    match => [ "Date", "YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
    locale => en
}
```

I added the `,SSS` so that the format match the one from the `Date` field.
The parsed date will be stored in the `@timestamp` field, unless specified differently with the `target` parameter.

Comment: Can I do `target => "Date"`  ... it will overwrite the initial "Date" ?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the `Date` field, replacing a string with a date. If the target option is not present, it will overwrite the `@timestamp` field

Comment: The official documentation says - "For non-formatting syntax, you’ll need to put single-quote characters around the value. For example, if you were parsing ISO8601 time, "2015-01-01T01:12:23" that little "T" isn’t a valid time format, and you want to say "literally, a T", your format would be this: "yyyy-MM-dd’T'HH:mm:ss""

Comment: Do I need to add the T as in `match => [ "Date", "YYYY-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" ]` ? Though my logs don't have a T .

Comment: Because by just doing what you said ..Kibana is showing Date as eg. 2016-01-06T23:27:32.797Z . I don't understand what the T and Z are for ?

Comment: If the date in your logs does not have a 'T', you don't have to. The date format must match what's in your logs.

Comment: But in your case, the mapping for `Date` is apparently a string, so the `Date` is saved as a string with the ISO8601 format, instead of a date. That's why `Date` appears in Kibana with T and Z. You won't be able to use `Date` as a date with this mapping.

Comment: You can't update a mapping (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/mapping.html#_updating_existing_mappings), you'll have either to write the date in another field (with `target => "another_Date_field"`) or delete your index and reindex your data.

Answer (score 4):

to check if your message contains a substring, you can do:

```
if [message] =~ "a" {
   mutate {
      add_field => { "hello" => "world" }
   }
}
```

So in your case you can use the if to invoke the drop{} filter, or you can wrap your output plugin in it.

To parse a date and write it back to your timestamp field, you can use something like this:

```
date {
    locale => "en"
    match => ["timestamp", "ISO8601"]
    timezone => "UTC"
    target => "@timestamp"
    add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
}
```

This matches my timestamp in:

- Source field: "timestamp" (see match)
- Format is "ISO...", you can use a custom format that matches your timestamp
- timezone - self explanatory
- target - write it back into the event's "@timestamp" field
- Add a debug field to check that it has been matched correctly

Hope that helps,

Artur