# logstash conf drop lines based on regex

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I've been playing with trying to filter out those log messages which have a category that I'm not interested in.

My log line looks like this....

```
2017-07-26 16:27:04,135 [[api-vehicle-registration-v1-114.0.0].apiHttpListenerConfig.worker.01] DEBUG esb.api-vehicle-registration-v1.get-registration.http.response - transactionID=6d5bec10-71cb-11e7-84ba-e2c437d94258 creationTime=2017-07-26T16:26:58.514+10:00 txnState=END timeTaken=5385 payloadType=JSON payload=[{"totalRecords":1}]
```

And i want to filter those log lines where the category doesn't match esb.*

Using the logstash.conf below my grok works but the drop bit doesn't. Can someone help me with that part of it ?

thanks

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{DATA:thread}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+%{JAVACLASS:category}\s+-\s+%{GREEDYDATA:msgbody}" ]
  }

  if [category] =~ /esb/ {
        drop { }
  }

  kv {
    # remove leading '[' and trailing ']'
    #include_brackets => true
    source => "msgbody"
  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop log messages containing a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068657/drop-log-messages-containing-a-specific-string)

Comment: Also I can't reproduce with the provided example;